# Publishing workflow for pages and lists

Tags: workflow, list, publishing-page, libraries

We need to create a publishing workflow on all lists and the Pages library in a site. We need the workflow to send an email when a user wants to publish minor or major versions of a publishing page or any of the lists on the site. It needs to go to an AD group which will provide approval, rejection, or request changes.

How should the workflow be created? Should we use the Library/List > Workflow Settings to do this? It seems inefficient to have to do this for each list on a site. Also, what settings should we choose when creating the workflow? Here are the settings we thought we should use for our scenario:

- All for the Content Type
- "Publishing Approval" for the Workflow
- "Workflow Tasks" for Task List
- "Workflow History" for History List
- Start Options:

  - [X] Start this workflow when a new item is created.
  - [X] Start this workflow when an item is changed.

Are these the correct settings for what we're trying to do? Your help and guidance are much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to do a large blanket workflow for all of your lists, you're better off attaching your workflow to your content types, this will minimize your configuration.

The rest of it looks good. Have a test box? Try it out first and see how it goes!

Comment: Thanks, David. A follow-up: How do you attach workflows to a content type but limit it to a particular web site? Each site will have its own approvers and content types span across all these webs. Should content types be per web? And each web site uses a dozen or so content types for the different lists, not one content type across all lists.

Comment: Maybe this will work: I can create an additional content type and attach it to all the lists in the site; this content type will have the workflow attached to it for the items in that web site.

Comment: Interesting note: For a content type with a workflow to work, it has to be set to "Visible on New Button" and as Default content type under the list/library's Advanced Settings. If all you want to do with it is to fire off the workflow, then hide the default Title column and your other columns on the list will display when the user hits "Add new item". Your users won't even know that content type has been added. Hope this helps somebody. Just figured it out via trial-and-error.